# Xamarin Forms - Change color of the Map Pin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, maps

I'm currently using Maps in Xamarin Forms. It works fine for this example.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/

Now i need to change just  the colour of the Pin, the following example is not really what i'm looking for as its a bit of an overkill for me.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin/

Is there an easier way to just change the color? I've tried:

```
var pin = new Pin                   {
Type = (data.contractDate>= DateTime.Now) ? PinType.SavedPin : PinType.Place
```

But this doesn't change the color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Xamarin Map control doesn't have that much customization support. It will just implement the basic cross-platform maps. If on the platform you're running on the color of a 'saved pin' and a 'place pin' is different then it will show a difference, but on another platform it will not. If you just need the pin customization, you can have a look at [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin/)

If you want to do this and maybe more, have a look at [TK Custom Map](https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap) for instance.

Answer (score 1):

you can using

```
marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.DefaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HueRed));
```

Tutorial below (not written by me)

https://montemagno.com/colored-map-markers-ios-and-android/